# in Bluemix, when i got this errorCall to undefined function mssql_connect()

Tags: ibm-cloud

In Bluemix, I created a PHP application and binded a new SQL service instance. However, when I try to connect to the SQL service instance, I received the following error:

```
Call to undefined function mssql_connect().
```

Can someone help me to explain why?
thanks

Comment: Please post relevant code. Can't solve your issue without

Comment: <?php


$serverName = "75.126.155.153";
$username = "user15298";
$password = "GnhtBEErQ4fg";
$database = "SQLDB_ZQ";

#DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE

$connection = mssql_connect('75.126.155.153', $username, $password);
  print("hello world");
?>

Comment: <?php


$serverName = "75.126.155.153";
$username = "user15298";
$password = "GnhtBEErQ4fg";
$database = "SQLDB_ZQ";



$connection = mssql_connect('75.126.155.153', $username, $password);
  print("hello world");
?>

Comment: Hi do you have the answer now? i am waiting.....

Comment: Where is your code is mssql_connect() defined?

Comment: $connection = mssql_connect('75.126.155.153', $username, $password)

Comment: That is defining a variable named connection, not the function mssql_connect. It can't find that function, hence why I am asking if and where it is defined

Comment: this function come with SQL server

Comment: I dont need to define it

Comment: I think Bluemix is missing some MSSQL driver from your PHP setup. Thats why it is asking mssql_connect() funciton

Comment: Sounds like that is the case

Comment: are you going to fix it?

Comment: Reference the documentation on Bluemix on how to connect to the SQL service with PHP. Have you tired that?

Comment: where is this document?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-bluemix-fundamentals-intro-to-sql-database-services-for-php-apps/index.html?ca=drs-

Comment: I have added build back in my manifest.yml:

Comment: buildpack: https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php

Comment: Alex's answer below should also be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments you are using the Bluemix SQLDB service, which is based on DB2.

There is a sample code in the link below for dashDB, but it is similar for SQLDB as well:

https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdatabase/dashDB/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/ibmdatabase%252FdashDB/list/master/samples/dashDBPHP

But basically, here is what you have to do:

```
//parse vcap
if( getenv("VCAP_SERVICES") ) {
    $json = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
} 
# No DB credentials
else {
    throw new Exception("No Database Information Available.", 1);
}    
# Decode JSON and gather DB Info
    $services_json = json_decode($json,true);
    $bludb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];

    // create DB connect string
    $conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};DATABASE=".
       $bludb_config["db"].
       ";HOSTNAME=".
       $bludb_config["host"].
       ";PORT=".
       $bludb_config["port"].
       ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=".
       $bludb_config["username"].
       ";PWD=".
       $bludb_config["password"].
       ";";

    // connect to database
    $conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
```

Finally, you have to use the DB2 Heroku PHP buildpack to deploy your application (the default PHP buildpack does not have db2 client):

```
$ cf push app-name -b https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php
```

Comment: Alex, should i change the ""username" to real username such as user123 and ""password" to "pass123"?

Comment: You don't need to if you use the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. I added one more piece of code showing how to read this env variable. It returns a json object with all the credentials to connect to your service.  Please see latest update on my answer.

Comment: i print out the $conn and it is Resource id #2 ; does this mean i connect it successfully?

Comment: i also get this error message during push
err
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/db2heroku-buildpack-php'..." and :"PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/app/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/apc.so' - /app/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0"